# Disable certain drop down list selections based on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements, dropdownlist

Let's say that in column A, users enter in different numbers. In column B, there are options of Y or N. If column A has a cell with the value of zero, it should disable the "N" option in column B. How do I do this?

Comment: A good phrase to Google for this is "Excel validation dependent list". Lots of resources exist explaining how to set this up. Enjoy.

Comment: Hey @Manfred H.,, are you using only one cell in Col A or many cells,, better share some sample data with us,, when (with How may Numbers) U need Y and N both !!

Answer (score 1):

If you can have actual entries of "Y or N" in column B (B1, say), then this is fairly straightforward.

If column B cannot have real entries in it, just the ghostly kind of entry one see on websites and other data forms, then Excel can't really do this for you.

So, enter `Y or N` in the cells of column B you need to. That will put the text reminder you desire in the B cells and ready your users for data entry.

The select cell B1. With it selected, open the Conditional Formatting function. Click `New Rule` and then the bottom choice in the top half, `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

The you need to enter the formula. Use the following formula:

```
=A1=0
```

and set the formatting. Set to what? Set the Numeric formatting and use a Custom format. Once there, highlight the word "General" that appears in the box and enter the following:

**;;;"Y"**

You are setting no format at all for positive, negative, and zero values in B1. This is so that any such entry will leave B1 blank. You could get more sophisticated than that with an additional rule or two. Lastly, the "Y" after the third ";" means that if the rule's condition is met, a capital "Y" will show in the cell.

And if not, the "true" cell contents of "Y or N" will show.

Last thing, after you set the rule and formatting is to look at the range of cells affected. Right now it is $B$1. Change it to whatever range you wish, though remember to only include cells in column B. More are unnecessary and will cause disturbing results.

There are a couple things to bear in mind:

1. Hugely important:  we used relative referencing (no "$" in the cell addresses:  "A1" not "$A$1"). That is so that you can use it all the way down column B as you need AND so that you can use it in the cell next to the entry cell in other columns if you need (like in collumn AB based on column AA).
2. For this to work, you MUST have an entry in the B1 cell. If it is blank, truly blank, not just a formula showing a blank, the conditional formatting will NOT show.
3. You COULD put the "Y or N" into a rule as well, but then the cells would be blank and the CF-ing would not show (see #1).
4. You can get more sophisticated if you need to consider A1 being utterly blank as not being the zero you are wanting to do this with — if you only want things to change if an actual entry of "0" is made.
5. You can use this approach in many cases, not just here. But usually you are hindered because when a cell is truly empty, like they normally are, the CF formatting will not show up.